# BitBucket doesn't import "wp" folder from WordPress-Skeleton

Tags: wordpress, github, bitbucket

Im trying for the first time to use Bitbucket togheter with SourceTree when building a WordPress site. Where working in a group of six people so I would really like to use the power of these services.

Right now im following this guide when trying to accomplish this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gx_XfziaHvo

I've also looked at several other guides and all of them say that i should base my WordPress site on markjaquith's WordPress-Skeleton base. 
https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton

The problem I've encountered is that when i start my Respository on BitBucket it does not import the folder "wp". Everything else is included but the folder "wp". Therefore I can't install WordPress. It's missing a massive amount of vital files.

After searching the internet and stackoverflow i can't seem to find a solution or any one else with the same problem! What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried importing the WordPress-Skeleton git directly in SourceTree but no luck there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... you'll have to add the wp folder to track it.

1. Use this: git add --all

$ git add --all

2. Next, use: git status (and you should see the wp folder and all new changes are added and being tracked)

$ git status

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly question, but did you check your **.gitignore** file?

Comment: Check it for what? .gitignore is included among the imported files, yes. But should this affect if the "wp" folder is downloaded?

Comment: It's possible that, in the .gitignore file, there's a line telling the git process not to import the WP directory into the repo.

Comment: After looking at the WordPress Skeleton documentation on github, it appears you won't need the wp directory in your repo since it's using a a Git submodule for the WP files. As such, your template files would be stored in the content directory.[WordPress Skeleton documentation](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton)

Comment: Ahh yeah i see. The problem is when I try to install WP localy later. The installation can't find the index.php. Is it possible that the ".gitmodules" is wrong?


[submodule "wp"]
 path = wp
 url = git://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git

Cause this must be the file fetching thte submodule?

Comment: I would give this a shot:
open a command line in the project directory

git submodule update
Submodule 'wp' (git://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git) registered for path 'wp'

This should pull the code from the registered submodule.

Comment: Yes it did! Didn't use the commandprompt though, used SourceTree instead but it worked. After i looked in to the "wp" directory i could, just as you said, pull the code from the submodule. Now my regular repository and the submodule work together! Thanks!